# How to remove single Quotes from parsing PHP Array into JSON?

Tags: php, json

Thats my result when i say `echo json_encode($array)`:

```
[{"name":"test"}]
```

I'm searching for something like replace. have php a method for replacing `strings` in `arrays`? The result should be this:

```
[{name:test}]
```

Comment: Have you actually searched for replace functions? Because PHP has loads... just [RTFM](http://www.php.net/str_replace). For more complex replacements [check this](http://www.php.net/preg_replace). Also: the first string is valid JSON, the second one isn't

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array();
$i = 1;
function replace($key)
{
  echo str_replace('"', '', $key)."<br />\n";
}


 $fruits = array("d" => '"lemon', "a" => '"orange', "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
 array_walk($fruits, 'replace');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP have `str_replace()` function.

```
$result = str_replace('"', '', json_encode($array));
```

Btw, according to [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), `[{"name":"test"}]` is the correct format. If you try to  parse `[{name:test}]` in JavaScript, JS will emit "test is not defined" error.